# How to compare three combobox and show result in textbox or label?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, combobox

[image: sample frame]
I am building inventory management system university project. The picture shows stock report.
i have 3 combo box and a text box for result. The problem is i don't know how to compare 3 combo box and count stock. for example when i choose Model: FZ, cc:153 and color : Red, the result in Total Stock should could and display in Total stock textbox.

```
 try
    {
        String searchmodel = cmbModelSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
        ps=DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(model)FROM stock WHERE model=?");
        ps.setString(1, searchmodel);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            lblCountResult.setText(rs.getString("count(model)"));

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: could you post some of the code so that we can understand what you are doing?

Comment: i used following code to count the model of biike for example (Enticer:3). The code will count available stock of enticer motorbike. But i need it to compare with CC and Color too

Comment: Not in the comments... make an edit to your post, this is very unclear

Comment: Please don't show code in comments as it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead please show it as an edit to your question, and please show more. You are asking about use of JComboBox -- so it would make sense for you to show that code, no?

Comment: yeah thats why i remove code from comment and add it on my post.

Comment: ... just not the right code. :/  Also, this is very wrong: `catch (Exception ex) {    }` and very dangerous. Always handle your exceptions.

Comment: Thats only a sample code for which i used to count model and display in label

Comment: Well, you should just add the 2 other combobox values to the sql query? What's the difficulty in that?

Comment: That's what i dont know how to so i post it on here

Comment: could you post the table structure of `stock` from your database or the SQL query that could be used to get the required result from the database

Comment: stock_id, Date, Model, Color, reg_no, Engine_Capacity, Engine_Number, Chasis_Number, Selling_Price
Above are Database field name and i used. 

SELECT COUNT(model)FROM stock WHERE model='fzs' GROUP BY 'cc' AND 'color' is query

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(model)FROM stock WHERE model=? AND CC = ? AND COLOR = ?" - I'm quessing at the column names, but something like that?

Comment: stock_id, Date, Model, Color, reg_no, Engine_Capacity, Engine_Number, Chasis_Number, Selling_Price  are column name of table

Comment: i already tried that query it works fine while i run it on mysql but problem in netbeans

Comment: use the query `SELECT COUNT(Model) FROM stock WHERE model = ? AND Engine_Capacity = ? AND Color = ?` and set the respective `JComboBox` values to each.

Comment: What is the problem in netbeans?

Comment: yes sir i make mistake on engine_capacity, i used cc instead of engine_capacity, finally problem solved, Thank very much @Blip.
one more question , how can i add select option on those combo box

Comment: It would be better if you could ask that in a separate question. Also I think @Manu gave you the correct answer as I edited the query. So it would be better to accept his answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be good:

Of course I don't know the actual names in your project & database, so I'm just guessing them.

```
String model = cmbModelSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
String cc = cmbCCSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
String color = cmbColorSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
ps=DbConnection.cn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(Model) FROM stock WHERE model = ? AND Engine_Capacity = ? AND Color = ?");
ps.setString(1, model);
ps.setString(2, cc);
ps.setString(3, color);
```

Comment: i will add some more model, cc, color in database and try this one again

Comment: @DipeshShrestha this query is based on guess the query you should use is `SELECT COUNT(Model) FROM stock WHERE model = ? AND Engine_Capacity = ? AND Color = ?` for your code

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is simply map the combo boxes' selection to a MySQL query (I suppose that's why you added the tag).

That's relatively simple. You just need to add an actionListener to the combo box. Every time someone changes the selected option (in either of the 3 combo boxes, actually), you will change a string (that is going to be used in the query)

Let's say that you have 3 strings:

```
String model;
String cc;
String color;
```

Every time someone changes any of the 3 combo boxes, you will set the respective string to the newly selected option. Note that if they are not selected, like in the screenshot, you will have to set the strings to be either `null` or empty. I prefer empty strings because they will save you from a few NPE down the road.

Now that you've set your strings according to the selected option, you will have to create a MySQL query based on that information. That's very simple - It's a select query with multiple (could be one) conditions.

It's going to look something like:

```
SELECT model, cc, color
FROM motorbikes
WHERE model=this.model AND cc=this.cc AND color=this.color;
```

But you have to be flexible when building the WHERE statement - if either of your strings is null or empty, then you must **not** include it in the query. This means that the first two lines of the above query are going to be your **base** - they won't be changing and we will be building on those. To check whether you should include any of the conditions (if they have been set from the combo box) you can do something like this:

```
boolean querySet = false;
String query = "SELECT model, cc, color FROM motorbikes ";
if(!model.isEmpty() || !cc.isEmpty() || !color.isEmpty()) {
    query.append("WHERE ");
    if(!model.isEmpty()) {
        query.append("model=" + this.model);
        querySet = true;
    }
    if(!cc.isEmpty()) {
        if(querySet){
            query.append("AND ");
        }
        query.append("cc=" + this.cc);
        querySet = true;
    }
    if(!color.isEmpty()) {
        if(querySet) {
            query.append("AND ");
        }
        query.append("color=" + this.color);
    }
}
```

After this, you should just send/receive the query and you are done. As a last step you only seem to be interested in the count of the motorbikes that are returned by this query (or perhaps you want to add an additional "AND currentStorage > 0)

Comment: Thanks, i get some knowledge here, will try this now

Comment: This is actually a bad option. It is always better to use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: There is a limited set of options available. He controls the labels in  the combo box by himself. There is no danger of SQL injection because the user doesn't provide direct input which is put into the query.

Comment: Still if you are suggesting the OP to use `Statement` over `PreparedStatement` you should also tell the downsides of `Statement` in you post.